# Wordpress speed optimization problems

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, optimization, wordpress-theming

I am facing issues from last weeks that my WordPress website with Bridge WP Theme is loading very low. I am doing optimisation with w3 total cache plugin with SSL and CDN Gtmetrix showing the following errors:

> - This page has 21 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
> - This page has 10 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.

I am using W3 Total Cache with minify feature but after enabling the minify Auto Option GT Metrix still shows that the page has 21 external Javascript scripts.

I need a permanent solution for that anyone can help me. And I want 100/100 score with GTmetrix and Google Page Speed. How it is possible? and especially on mobile, it's running very very slow

I have tried the following:

- I already use W3 total cache with SSL.
- I also try its manual feature of minifying but its manual feature does not solve my problem.

#### The results

W3 Total Cache Plugin:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymi5W.jpg

Without W3 Total Cache Plugin:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQKwS.jpg

Google page speed
Google page speed is very very slow mostly 9 on mobile and 34 on desktop.

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic%7CMontserrat%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic&subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&ver=1.0.0
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Ld5LbgUAAAAABEoimqlML9XFzNhxeAt_xrTEFfq&ver=3.0
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/webworker.js?hl=en&v=Zy-zVXWdnDW6AUZkKlojAKGe

386.8KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

```
wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js (132.7KiB)
wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js (97.5KiB)
wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js (86.8KiB)
wp content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js (48.9KiB)

wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js (7.7KiB)

wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-migrate.min.js (1.1KiB)][1]
```

Comment: Try tidying your question up a bit bud, it's hard to read. The answer is that W3 total cache will minify and combine some files but not all. You will need to do this manually if you want to get it to only 1 / 2 JS and CSS files. If you want 100%.....do as the tool tells you!! I would instead focus on getting your page size under 1MB and total requests under 20 before worrying about the last few percent on a scoring system as those are going to be your biggest issues especially for mobile speeds.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In w3 total cache minify manual settings. I selected all the js files to be async but its showing errors in the console browser. please help me. This is settings in w3 total cache  https://imgur.com/DNp0JK1 and this is my console errors  https://imgur.com/Es0jj8Y   please help me out what is perfect solution THANKS

Comment: You can't do async without coding for it. try defer instead. the reason for this is async will run JS files the second they are ready so your scripts load out of order if one loads earlier than something it relies on.

Comment: Thanks for this GTmetrix is showing these issue in defer parsing of javascript https://q7q4x8r5.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/cache/minify/eff97.js
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/Zy-zVXWdnDW6AUZkKlojAKGe/recaptcha__en.js (215.7KiB) (its google v3 recaptcha)
https://q7q4x8r5.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/cache/minify/143ef.js
https://q7q4x8r5.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/cache/minify/864c2.js 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.js (16.8KiB
https://afiamalikdesign.com/ (13.3KiB)   please tell me how I can defer or async these files in w3 total cache

Comment: read the documents bud, in fact just go into the settings, you cant miss the minification settings section and if you play around you will see `defer` in one of the settings. Give it a go, raise another question if you struggle or do a search on google for W3 Total Cache Defer JS / CSS there will be loads of tutorials.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I did my best settings with w3 total cache docs but my on google page speed mobile it's running very very slow check this image and link https://imgur.com/0THCFxV. please help me with these issues. I am really very confused

Comment: There is far too much for me to help you with on here, took me weeks to learn it all and it isn't a case of 'install x' or 'change y' I am afraid. Your best bet is to google each item you fail on with phrases like 'how to improve...x' you will see loads of information. For example the 'defer offscreen images' is asking you to lazy load images that are not needed to paint 'above the fold' content so look into lazy loading images first and take it one item at a time. Ask new questions on here for each item as you get stuck, show what you have tried and I can help you that way.

Comment: CDN YSlow

 6 static components that are not on CDN.

https://afiamalikdesign.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.2.3
https://afiamalikdesign.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js?version=5.4.8
https://afiamalikdesign.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?version=5.4.8

Answer (score 0):

These scripts that are so big are added by revolution slider.

Revolution slider's settings allow you to at least lazyload Images but it doesn't solve its biggest problem, that it's actually massive in terms of JS that it adds to the page. If you start deferring these scripts, you might run into issues with revslider, not working slider etc. Here is a nice article about that: https://wp-rocket.me/blog/fastest-wordpress-image-slider-2019/

I would recommend to look for a similar slider plugin, but more simple. I see for example, that you don't use video on your site, so you already don't need half of the code that revslider adds. The article above gives a nice overview for already better sliders. [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slider-wd/) is also a slider that loads less scripts but I haven't tested it myself. Usually it's better to code a slider yourself and fix them up with shortcodes so you can place them anywhere. [There](https://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/wordpress-image-slider/) is an article that kinda matches with what I mean.

I'll update this post with more info, as I am working on an article with a detailed explanation on how to built your own performance optimised wordpress plugin for sliders.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try, wp-Rocket and Smush, don't go with combine CSS and JS it will make issue. [image]